# Rows and Columns in iPhone Application Programming

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview

How can I get 5x5 Table in my iPhone application ? (Using `UICustomViewCell` I can have only one column).

EDIT :

I am talking about the below table. Can I get it like that in iPhone?

[image: Table]

Comment: Sorry Akshay, I am not able to see the image you have added, as its banned in my office, I have posted one approach anyhow, see if it helps.

Comment: No need to be sorry Vaibhav. Thanks for the approach. What the image says is suppose - I want a 5x5 Table to show. How can I do that ?No taps and all for showing detail view or something. Only a 5x5 Table with some data .

Comment: For me its simple, Create a custom Cell, add proper background Image which will divide the cell in 5 different columns, add five labels in these columns. Have property set for these labels. Add this custom cell instead of normal cell, and you can easily give a look and feel of 5x5 grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody has mentioned it, so I'll do it. If you need this table basically for display purposes, and don't need much native interaction you can as well create the table in html and show it in a UIWebView.

I use a similar approach in one of my apps:
[image]

It's not that hard to create a simple html table from your data.

Comment: +1 For Fluchtpunkt, as these seems to be correct and easy approach.This will be tedious free and timing saving.The guy can make the table inn html and can also use the href to give some action on click or what ever,then he needs to implement the delegate method of WebView in order to implement the action on particular item.He can give the image path in html with href attribute,as i have done something for providing actions as well in the webview with html href.But that was not using so much rows.Heads off for you for helping that guy in time and providing him with better solution

Comment: Thanks a lot @fluchtpunkt and @Sabby ... It worked very fine. Now I am trying for dynamic data. Hope will try to find out soon. :)

Answer (score 1):

*UITableView* only supports one column. This was an iOS design decision taken due to the much smaller nature of the original iPhone and then iPad screens.

If you wanted to have more than one columns then you'd have to create your own class that perhaps includes multiple *UITableViews*, or your own custom *UIControl*. I think if you were to attempt this you'd find yourself fighting the framework and you'd be misunderstanding the nature of apps for these platforms.

Perhaps you should consider using a *UINavigationController*, *UITabBarController*, or some other means of navigating the app, with multiple *UITableViews* in order to present information to the user?

Hope this helps.

**Response to Edit:**

In a word... no.

In more than a word, yes - you just can't achieve this using the traditional and reccomended *UITableView*. As I said before, consider rearranging your data so as you only display a certain amount at a time. For example, you could have one *UITableView* that displays a list of all the batch codes, and when the user taps on one of the cells, a second *UITableView* could be transitioned to (using a *UINavigationController*) that displays the more detailed info of 'beginning control #', 'beginning sequence #' etc. etc. This sort of user interface is what you see all over apps on the iOS platform.

Alternatively, you could create a custom *UIView* or *UIControl* subclass that displays the information exactly you'd like it, perhaps by overriding the `drawRect:` method. But imagine how the example you've given above would look like on an iPhone in portrait mode... Not very good and not very user friendly. You could perhaps also use an image for the table, and allow the user to scroll over the image as they would when zoomed in the Photos app. You could embed custom controls into a scroll view to achieve this. But again, the user interface probably wouldn't meet the standards for ease of use, simplicity and clarity that users expect from iOS apps. In my opinion, the best solution here is to figure out a way to logically split your data across multiple *UITableViews*. Try taking a good look at what some of the other apps out there do and how they manage to really effectively get around the small space problem. :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please look at the QUESTION EDIT , Thanks for response. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using tableview you cant achieve this.but if your design is static you can achieve this by  using images.

Comment: Please look at the QUESTION EDIT , Thanks for response. :)

Comment: I was going to write about images in my response too. I think we've got a little confused because we've seen an image as an example of what Akshay wants and thought that it's a solution! The problem with images is that they're obviously completely static and thus cannot possibly allow dynamic changing of the data model to be displayed! In this example the desired table is clearly showing information about a branch which is likely to be changed. However, if dynamic information isn't a requirement, then this is a possible (although still unadvisable) solution.

Comment: @Akshay:I think you figured it out.If not create a Imageview or Button using IB add all the labels you want just like your design. and  use the proper background image

Answer (score 0):

```
Id | Name | Address | Designation | Dept
-----------------------------------------
1  | ABC  | addr    | DM          | IT
-----------------------------------------
2  | ASD  | addr    | PM          | IT
-----------------------------------------
3  | XYZ  | addr    | TL          | IT
-----------------------------------------
4  | QWE  | addr    | PM          | IT
-----------------------------------------
5  | ZXC  | addr    | TL          | IT
-----------------------------------------

Lets assume you have to show the data in above format. Then as said by James, you can go for Custom Cells. Or you can show a table you showing only names of the Employees as in - 

-----------------------------------------
ABC
-----------------------------------------
ASD
-----------------------------------------
XYZ
-----------------------------------------
QWE
-----------------------------------------
ZXC
-----------------------------------------


And then when you select any particular employee you can navigate to a details page, showing all the details of that particular employee. or you can simply expand that particular cell and show the details of that employee

-----------------------------------------
ABC

Address     - addr

Designation - DM

Department  - IT
-----------------------------------------
ASD
-----------------------------------------
XYZ
-----------------------------------------
QWE
-----------------------------------------
ZXC
-----------------------------------------
```